# Browserify __dirname in unix style

Tags: node.js, browserify

Can I specify for browserify to use unix format style for __dirname?

I need to use path module in the browser to get basename from __dirname, here is the code:

```
var path = require('path');
var basename = path.basename(__dirname);
```

By default, on windows, browserify sets __dirname in windows format (like "..\dir\file.txt") then in browser I get incorect basename. Instead of `file.txt` I get `..\dir\file.txt`.

[Here](https://github.com/substack/path-browserify/blob/master/index.js#L54) I see that path-browserify contains only unix version of path split regex.